# On press - fire method?

Tags: angularjs

In angular, I have a radio button that is used to show and hide elements on my form.

I also wish to fire some javascript, when a certain radio button is pressed?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-click` or `ng-change` directives. Example

```
<input type='radio' ng-click='radioClick()' />
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.radioClick = function() {
    console.log("You just clicked a radio!");
}
```

Comment: And how do I link that up to my js file?